# MongoDB update field or upsert new document

Tags: mongodb, upsert

I'm trying to update a field in a Document if exists, if not I want to upsert the entire document. Is it possible without running two queries, one for searching the document and another for update/insert?

This is where I've stuck (`product` and `shopId` are variables):

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  { "ref": product.ref, "sizesData.shop": shopId },
  { "$set": { "sizesData.$": { "$max": { "mostRecentPrice": product.price } } },
  { upsert: true }, },
)
```

I'm trying to update the `mostRecentPrice` in the `sizesData` subdocument if the document exists. But I want to create an entirely new document if the Document does not exists. Is it possible in a single query? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use [the positional operator with upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#upsert):

> Do not use the positional operator $ with upsert operations because inserts will use the $ as a field name in the inserted document.

so it seems like you need to hit the database more than once

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I dind't see it in the docs... Thanks!